# UDP vs TCP in local network application with application-level ack system

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp

i have a question about the trasport layer of the iso/osi network stack.
It's common to think that TCP is reliable but slow and UDP is fast but not reliable.
In several network applications, it is mandatory to implement an application-level ACK system also with TCP transport protocol in order to manage link interruptions and so on.
Assuming that the application scenario is this: local (small) network, typical small packet size (max 512 bytes), application-level ack system implementation. Why not use the protocol UDP as transport protocol in order to exploit its features such as speed, low latency and broadcast communication?

Thanks to all.

Comment: In a local network speed and latencies are very seldom a problem.

Comment: Also, with TCP why would anyone need application-level acknowledgement messages? If a link goes down you will get an error (possible after a timeout).

Comment: Ok. Application level ack are useless because they are guaranteed by the same tcp level. However broadcast communication is a helpful functionality in the case where there are many nodes that need to communicate to each other without a central (master node). Udp + Application level ack are able to guarantee the "same" reliability of the Tcp protocol?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg TCP doesn't provide indications of link failure unless you actually send data.  That's why BSD sockets have the KEEPALIVE option.

Comment: @RossPatterson. I'm confused. Classic TCP library implementations of the different languages (c#, java etc) handle link errors? For example, a blocking send returns if and only if the related ack packet is received by the library (kernel probably)? If not the only way to be sure that the packet is arrived at the destination is a application level ack message. It's correct?

Comment: @user2957271 Sure.  Most libraries deal with the ack failing arrive within a timeout period, and aborting operations.  But TCP doesn't specify that behavior.  Some TCP's (_e.g._ the KA9Q package) would retransmit forever instead.

Comment: Application level ack are important also with TCP protocol. What happens if the receiver receive the packet (and send the tcp ack to sender) but the application or machine go down (for some reasons like power fail, hardware/software bugs etc ...)? In some applications application-level ack are mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the Delivery (failure or successful delivery) of your message than UDP will be always a best choice.. But if you want to be sure whether the message is delivered or failed than think about other protocols rather than UDP.

Answer (score 1):

In a small LAN it shouldnt be a big problem to use UDP, when the transferd Data isnt too "important" (which means if a packet is lost its no problem). More informations about the scenario are nessesary, if you use UDP you have to implement functions that check if you received all the information of the sender manually.

if you need the speed and if some lost packets are no problem (Voice Chat for instance) then use UDP.

Comment: The data delivery is important in my scenario but i can implement all the delivery mechanisms at application level. Think a scenario where there are many nodes that need to communicate to each other without a central (master node). Network must be dynamic. UDP broadcast is very convenient in my opinion.